# How to swap columns and rows in a matrix with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

All I want to do is swap `matrix[i][j]` with `matrix[j][i]` using `while` loops. Why doesn't this work?

```
def my_transpose(matrix)

  new_matrix = []

  i = 0
  j = 0

  while i < matrix.size
    new_matrix[i] = []
    while j < matrix.size
      new_matrix[i] << matrix[j][i]
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  return new_matrix
end
```

If I run this with something like

```
[
[1,2,3],
[1,2,3],
[1,2,3]
]
```

it just returns `1,1,1`. How do I get it to return `1,1,1; 2,2,2; 3,3,3` ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply use transpose from Array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `j = 0`  within the `i` loop

```
def my_transpose(matrix)

  new_matrix = []

  i = 0


  while i < matrix.size
    new_matrix[i] = []
    j = 0  # move this here
    while j < matrix.size
      new_matrix[i] << matrix[j][i]
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  return new_matrix
end
```

If `j` is not reset to 0 for every `i` loop then it never enters the `j` loop except for the first time:

```
i = 0
j = 0
# Enter i loop
 new_matrix[0] = []
 # Enter j loop
  new_matrix[0] << matrix[0][0] 
  j += 1 #=> 1

  new_matrix[0] << matrix[1][0] 
  j += 1 #=> 2

  new_matrix[0] << matrix[2][0] 
  j += 1 #=> 3
 # Exit j loop
 i += 1 #=> 1

 new_matrix[1] = []
 # Does not enter j loop as j = 3 > matrix.size
 i += 1 #=> 2

 new_matrix[2] = []
 # Does not enter j loop as j = 3 > matrix.size
 i += 1 #=> 3
# Exit i loop
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why 'j = 0' has to be moved?

Answer (score 20):

If your question is *How to swap columns and rows in a matrix with Ruby*, the answer is to use the built-in [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose)

```
a = [
[1,2,3],
[1,2,3],
[1,2,3]
]
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
a.transpose
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: I don't want to use that though... I'm trying to create my own.

Comment: I upvote because this is indeed my question and this post has good Google ranking

Answer (score 1):

You can use parallel assignment for this, e.g. `a,b = b,a`. As a side note, `while` loops are very seldom used in Ruby, branding you as a rookie. A more Ruby-like way would be using enumerators like `times`, `upto`, `downto`, etc., which will handily already provide the indices `i` and `j` as a loop variable. When you store the methods in the Array class you additionally can save yourself to type `matrix` over and over again, because you're already inside the class. Besides, it is very common to write a mutator method first (altering the original object, commonly denoted by a bang `!` at the end of the method name), and then writing an additional non-mutator method which simply calls the mutator on a duplicate. Here's how I would write the code:

```
class Array
  def my_transpose!
    size.times do |i|
      0.upto(i) do |j|                                   # iterate only through lower half
        self[i][j], self[j][i] = self[j][i], self[i][j]  # swap rows and cols
      end
    end
    self                                                 # return the array itself
  end

  def my_transpose
    dup.map(&:dup).my_transpose!                         # inner arrays are dup'ed, too
  end
end
```

Interestingly, Ruby's builtin `transpose` is not available as a mutator. Here's how to use the above code:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

a.my_transpose!                        # mutator
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

a
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]  # note that a changed

a.my_transpose!
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  # a is back to its original state

a.my_transpose                         # non-mutator
#=> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]

a
#=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]  # note that a did not change
```

Answer (score 0):

When you transpose a m x n matrix, the columns become the rows and vice versa. If the array doesn't have the same number of rows and columns you need to iterate from i to matrix[0].size since the number of columns in each element need to be the number of rows in the transposed matrix.

```
def my_transpose(matrix)

  new_matrix = []

  i = 0


  while i < matrix[0].size # this will create correct number of rows
    new_matrix[i] = []
    j = 0
    while j < matrix.size
      new_matrix[i] << matrix[j][i]
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end

  return new_matrix
end
```